# 3 Tabs with Maskvisibilities

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to create a maskvisibility code for this delay block I am programming. Right now I have 3 tabs all with the same parameters. Lets call the tabs x,y, and z. The parameters that are in the tabs we'll call 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. In parameter 2, for all tabs, is a drop down menu. This menu contains options s, t and u. I know how to make the parameters invisible with the "on" "off" option. The problem I am having is that when I am in tab x and I choose s it will make all the other tabs only show s. My idea to fix this is to have get the parameters for the other tabs and transpose them into the maskvisibility code I have but I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.